# C: difference in behaviour of scanf and getchar

Tags: c, char, int, scanf, getchar

I wanted to write a function to in C to read characters until a newline is encountered. I wrote the following codes using scanf and getchar:

Code using scanf : 
`while(scanf("%c",&x)!=EOF&&x!='\n'){....}`

Code using getchar : `while(((x=getchar())!=EOF)&&x!='\n'){....}`

int x is a local variable declared inside the function. The second code stops after reading word (EG: "ADAM\n"), while scanf code does not break the loop and keeps on waiting.

Later I found that after scanf, x's value was (2^7-1)*(2^8) + ascii value of character read ( = 32522 for newline), while character constant '\n' was 10. So the comparison was failing.

My question is that why scanf assigns a value > 32000 to x after reading '\n', while getchar assigns a value 10( which matches with character constant '\n') ?

Comment: `scanf("%c",&x)==EOF` are you serious?

Comment: I am sorry. That was a mistake. I have corrected that line @SouravGhosh

Comment: corrected with what? The return value of scanf() is important.

Comment: So, I am comparing return value of scanf with EOF. Is it not the correct way ?Please correct me.@SouravGhosh

Comment: Yes, that's not a problem itself, but the issue there is, how do you know `scanf()` is success, in first place? In case `scanf()` fails, you will invoke UB by accessing the target variable (if not initialized already).

Comment: Please tell the full form of UB @SouravGhosh

Comment: Did you take a look at the documentation for both functions?

Answer (score 0):

The key difference here is in the `scanf` behavior:

1) in general `scanf` is used to read different data types (not only `char`), for example `scanf("%d",&num)` will read integer number and ignore all "space" characters (characters as ' ' (space), '\t' (tab) and '\n' (new line)).

2) `scanf("%c",&x)` as well as `scanf("%d",&num)` (if number was entered) will return 1 - number of successfully data read from `stdin`. Note: `scanf("%d",&num)` will return `0` if not number is in `stdin`.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that scanf does skip whitespace characters in the input stream, while getchar returns them. So you can't see newlines in the input with scanf. Also the return value of scanf is the number of successful converted variables.

You need to check for `scanf(...) == 1` to see, if the variable contains a valid value ([more details here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)). When scanf did not converted all the input variables, the value of the not converted variables is undefined. This is why you see the strange value for x in your case. This is just some (more or less) random value caused by the fact that the compiler assigned x to a memory location, which was used before, and still contains some left over data.